# usage of unless when we need double negation in if-clause

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, conjunctions, conditional-constructions, grammaticality-in-context

Once I thought it was wrong to use *not* after *unless*, but then I found the following example on the internet:

> I cannot go to the cinema unless I don’t go to the restaurant.

And now I'm trying to understand more about the usage of *unless* (it beats me why I cannot use it properly).

I can make the following examples with *if/only if/except if* (which some believe it's ungrammatical) or *otherwise/provided that/on condition that....* if one is possible; and if not, just rephrase it.

But I specifically want to know if I can use *unless* in a sentences like:

> - I pronounce every word in British unless I don't know how it's pronounced. (Intended meaning: .... if I know how it's pronounced in British, if not I pronounce it in American)
> - I wouldn't ask him to bring his car unless I knew you didn't bring yours. (Instead of: I wouldn't ask him to bring his car if I didn't know you didn't bring yours. Which I admit it's clunky).

It would be much appreciated if you demonstrate how it's properly used.

Note: my question is about the grammaticality not the naturalness of this usage.

Comment: American and British are not languages, for your information.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing forbids a negation after "*unless*". Whatever comes after "*unless*" designates the condition under which the preceding statement doesn't apply.

Comment: Very simple and well said!